# is there a way to improve this default delphi XE3 touch screen behaviour?

Tags: delphi, touch

is there a way to improve this default delphi XE3 touch screen behaviour?

supposing we have our delphi application with a couple of edit boxes running on a touch screen computer.  there's some very strange behaviour I'm having some trouble with.

I'll describe making the application:

1. start a new delphi XE3 app "New VCL Metropolis UI Application", "Blank Metropolis UI Application".
2. drop a couple of edit boxes on the form (we'll call them Edit1 and Edit2).
3. compile and deploy to touch screen computer
   on touch screen computer:
4. run our new app
5. touch in Edit1 (virtual keyboard appears nicely)
6. touch in Edit1 again (virtual keyboard disappears...ok???)
7. touch in Edit1 (virtual keyboard appears and then very quickly disappears)
8. touch in Edit1 (virtual keyboard appears and then very quickly disappears)
9. touch in Edit1 (virtual keyboard appears and then very quickly disappears)

Man, that "sucks"...the only way you can get the keyboard back is to touch Edit2 and then go back to Edit1.

how can I make this work properly?  I can't possibly expect my users to use this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided not to use the virtual keyboard provided by the VCL/windows.  Decided for now to use the TTouchKeyboard that comes with delphi and the CM_FOCUS message.